# div width property with content

Tags: html, stylesheet

I have two div and they have some width. But I want each div to take full space as it's given in width property regardless of the content inside div s. Currently each div is taking space with respect to the content inside them and ignoring what is given in width property.

My HTML is given below,

```
  <div style="margin-left:100px; display:inline;  border-width:10px; width:30%; border-     style:solid;">
fawad
</div>
<div style=" margin-left:10px;  display:inline; border-width:10px; width:30%; border-style:solid">ali</div>
```

Comment: can you include a jsfiddle. Also have you tried `display:inline-block;`

Comment: this is it. Thanks aaronmallen. It worked thanks again

Comment: Is there any particular reason you're using inline styles?

Comment: I want to create portal style website design so many div s in one straight line and there can be any number of div s. If u have any better idea please let me know. I dont want to use float because it ran outside from footer

Comment: I would use a css style sheet and apply all these settings to a class, I will edit my answer.

Comment: I have edited my answer in this post have a look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change your

```
display:inline;
```

to:

```
display: inline-block;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/osx76nbr/

Answer (score 2):

You can use css property `display:inline-block;`.That is help to set div inline with block.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply a `display` block style.  In this case I would apply

```
<div style="margin-left:100px; display:inline-block;  border-width:10px; width:30%; border-     style:solid;">
fawad
</div>
<div style=" margin-left:10px;  display:inline-block; border-width:10px; width:30%; border-style:solid">ali</div>
```

Alternatively I would apply all of these settings to a style sheet and apply a class to the div instead of having inline styles like this.

```
.inline-div {
    display: inline-block;
    border: 10px solid;
    width: 30%;
}

<div class="inline-div"></div>
```

Even better is I would look into a grid system much like the ones found in [bootstrap](http://www.getbootstrap.com) or [foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/).  That way you can just apply the grid styles.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-4">
    <div class="col-4">
    <div class="col-4">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Only thing that was needed

```
display:inline-block;
```

That's it

Answer (score -1):

Try adding

```
div { float:left }
```

That will make the divs respect the with property.

Comment: This will not fix that his div's are not applying his weight property.